# Deploy ui5 application to ABAP Repository from SAP Business Application Studio

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori, ui5-tooling

I have a custom ui5 app which is already deployed in the ABAP Repository. Currently I'm new to this ui5. I have made some changes in the `view.xml` file. I want to deploy the changes into the SAP system. Is it mandatory to have cloud connector configured to deploy ui5 changes from SAP Business Application Studio? Or configuring the destination is enough? I'm using a client machine, I'm unable to install SAP cloud connector.

Pour some pointers on how to deploy ui5 to SAP ABAP repository.

I have added destination with the proper necessary properties with hostname of system and all. I'm expecting the steps to deploy ui5 application to ABAP repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it via cloud connector is certainly the preferred way of doing it. You just need to run the NPM script `deploy-config` in your application studio project to generate a deployment configuration. It will then prompt you for the name of your connection to the ABAP backend system (configured in the BTC cockpit under Connectivity->Destinations), the technical name of the app, the package you want it to be in and the transport request. This will generate a file `ui5-deploy.yaml`, which you can later edit manually should any of these things change. Once you have that file, you can run the script `deploy` to push the application to your ABAP system.

But when you don't have a cloud connector set up, then there is an alternative way. You can export the whole project in the Application Studio as a TAR archive by right-clicking on the `webapp` folder of your app and selecting "Download". You can then unpack that TAR file into the filesystem of your own PC and then upload it into the ABAP system using the report `/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD`.